# My PHP is working locally, but not on 1and1 server

Tags: php, html, session-variables

I have tested the following script locally on my machine and everything works perfectly the way I want it. However, when I upload my files to my server at 1and1, on the log-in script when I click the "submit" button, it just stays on the log-in screen.

I'm also not sure, but perhapes the problem isn't with sessions, but with use of my header function.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require ("login.php");
    include ("header.php");
    include ("subnav.php");

    if ((isset($_SESSION['user'])) && (isset($_SESSION['admin'])))
        header('Location: admin/index.php' );

    if ((isset($_SESSION['user'])) && (!isset($_SESSION['admin'])))
        header('Location: customer/index.php' );

    if ((isset($_GET['logout'])) == 1) {
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        if($_POST['username'] == 'jay') {
            $_SESSION['user'] = 'jay';
            $_SESSION['admin'] = 1;
            header('Location: admin/index.php' );
        }
        else if ($_POST['username'] == 'william'){
            $_SESSION['user'] = 'william';
            header('Location: customer/index.php' );
        }
        else {
            header('Location: http://www.google.com' );
        }
?>

    <h2>System Log-In</h2>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <ul id="login">
            <li>
                Username: <br>
                <input type="text" name="username"></li>
            <li>
                Password: <br>
                <input type="password" name="password">
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Log-In" name ="submit" id="submit">
            </li>
            <li>
                <br><a href=#>Register Here.</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                If you are having problems with the log-in process, please send us an <a href="mailto:here@here.us">e-mail</a>.
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>


<?php   
    include ("footer.php");
?>
```

[image]

Comment: May be the session is disabled. `session_start` return a boolean, you have to check that boolean to know if the session has started successfully or not. From the documentation: This function returns TRUE if a session was successfully started, otherwise FALSE

Comment: Its the `.htaccess` setting that 1and1 put in place that is blocking everything. Due a request, I began working again with PHP on 1and1  and I am regretting it accepting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put curly braces at this point in the code to properly complete the block of code:

```
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
```

In general, it is best to always use curly braces for all if statements even if they are one line. This helps to prevent confusion problems like this.

Comment: That didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: Another thing to do is to add echo statements throughout the if statements so you can tell which path is being followed. This will greatly help with troubleshooting. Once you know where the wrong path is being taken, you can focus in on the value of those key variables.

Comment: I placed an echo right before the 'header('Location....) line and the echo message printed out but of coursse, the browser redirect didn't occur

Comment: No output can be sent from the server before calling header('Location...') for it to redirect. So the echo would prevent it from redirecting. However, because it was not working before this, I am assuming other output is being sent. Is one (or more) of your login.php, header.php, or subnav.php sending any html output? An easy to try to see what is being output is to view source and see what shows up before your echo.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, because on my local server there were no problems with the redirects.

Comment: Is 1and1 outputting anything before your file? Any html at the top of the page or even blank lines? That could explain why it works locally, but not on the server. Again, the view source feature of your browser can be extremely helpful here.

Comment: 1and1 doesn't output anything. Your suggestion to remove the includes down below the headers worked, but I don't know why. Locally, I was outputting text before the redirects and was receiving no problem.

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not help but there are a few things you should get in order:

1. When using the `Location:` header you should always terminate the script using `die()`. Otherwise the rest of the script will keep running: `header('Location: ...'); die;`
2. Also related to the `Location:` header, you really should put a forward slash in-front of the path. E.g. `Location: /index.php`.
3. I hope the code is for practice. Giving a user admin status simply based on the value of a POST variable is not exactly very secure.

Comment: No, this is just for testing - the values will be derived from a database.